# Get specific h3 from multiple cloned divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a specific h3 from a cloned div when pressing a button. Since I got 10 cloned divs with the exact same values I want to be able to get the h3 from the specific button I just pressed.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btnFavorite", function() {
    var favoriteMovieTest = $(this).parent().find("h3");
    alert(favoriteMovieTest);
});
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-result">
    <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
    <input type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">
    <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that you want to change `var favoriteMovieTest = $("this").parent().find("h3");` to `var favoriteMovieTest = $(this).parent().find("h3");` Your code is looking for a <this> html element which doesn't exist.

Comment: ye thanks, will edit this. But still doesn't sovle my problem. Also why is people downvoting...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**Note** : Keep code to attach event handler after `for` loop because if it is executed before `for` loop, elements created by for loop won't be attached with a event handler.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").find("h3").append(" "+i);
}

$(".btnFavorite").on("click", function() {
    var favoriteMovieTest = $(this).siblings("h3")[0];
    console.log(favoriteMovieTest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-result">
    <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
    <input type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">
    <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hm this doesn't seem to work in my code, also wouldn't this only get the first element [0]?

Comment: No. Your code has all same element so you think it is getting the same element each time. Let me do some modification to show you some difference.

Comment: Your sample code only has one h3. jquery will return an array and to target the element you want to use [0] which gives you h3. You can try `debugger` and test what is `$(this)` returning to you and play with it in console to solve the issue.

Comment: @Amar Made some minor changes to the code, have a look at it. It should clear your doubt.

Comment: yes I do know all my example code only has the same h3, but I tried this on my actual code and the alert  gave me the output 
`[object HTMLHeadingElement]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search");
}

$(".btnFavorite").on("click", function() {
    var favoriteMovieTest = $(this).closest("div").find("h3");
    favoriteMovieTest.css('color','red');    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-result">
    <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
    <input type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">
    <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i get that specific `h3` element from the button.
Now you can do whatever you like with it, for example manipulate it's `CSS` code to change the color, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can climb up and down the DOM to get and title or index number of which cloned element was clicked.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".search .btnFavorite", function(e) {
  var elIndex = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children).indexOf(e.target.parentNode);
  var favoriteMovieTest = e.target.parentNode.innerText;

  alert('H3: ' + favoriteMovieTest + ' index: ' + elIndex);
});
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-result">
    <h3 id='title'>Title(year)</h3>
    <input type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">
    <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
  </div>
</div>
```